# Starting : can't open [/data/db/mongodb.log] for log file: errno:13 Permission denied

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, linode

I can not run mongodb in ubuntu 10.04 lucid in linode.

I'm following this guide http://library.linode.com/databases/mongodb/ubuntu-10.04-lucid#sph_id4 but when I try run the commands:

/etc/init.d/mongodb start
/etc/init.d/mongodb stop

I get the error:

```
Starting : can't open [/data/db/mongodb.log] for log file: errno:13 Permission denied
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: It appears that you do not have adequate privileges for writing to the log file.

Comment: Thank you the problem was fixed with http://support.vamosa.com/kb/discovery/installing-mongodb-on-ubuntu-1004-lts